# Filtering array of arrays (best approach)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Input: `X = [[0, 2, 4], [1, 4], [2, 0], [3], [4, 0, 1]]`

So I have this array where I have to iterate through to filter it as follow:

`X[0] = [0, 2, 4]` so I have to remove every 0, 2 and 4 from all succeeding arrays to get:`X = [[0, 2, 4], [1], [], [3], [1]]`

`X[1] = [1]` so I have to remove every 1 from X[2], X[3] and X[4] to get:`X = [[0, 2, 4], [1], [], [3], []]`

`X[2] = []`, there is nothing to remove

`X[3] = [3]`, have to remove 3 from X[4] which is empty

Final output would be: `[[0, 2, 4], [1], [], [3], []]`

I can easily do that using for loops but I was thinking if you can advise me on some library or python functions to do it quicker or with less code. Can numpy library help me here? I would appreciate some input on this, thank you.

Comment: Does the order in your sub-lists matter? or is it just you want to remove the duplicates?

Comment: And what is your effort so far with the loops. I think you eventually need to do some sort of loops, you might be able to optimize your loop though.

Comment: Actually, I just need to remove the duplicates in the arrays that follow. I am thinking of doing a double loop to iterate through all list to compare it with the following lists and remove duplicates

Comment: You probably can do it with single loop. but now that you dont care about the order, you can use sets. I will post a solution on that.

Comment: I need a double loop to iterate through each list with the lists that it follow. For example for X[0] i need to check X[0] with X[1], X[0] with X[2] etc.. then for X[1] I need to check X[1] with X[2] etc..

Comment: Please find my post with single loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution if orders in inner lists doesn't matter:

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import flatten
X = [list(set(X[i])-set(flatten(X[:i]))) for i in range(len(X))]
```

output:

```
[[0, 2, 4], [1], [], [3], []]
```